# Xmodelimporter for netbeans

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a project working that loads and displays X3D models. I've read that `xmodelimporter` is meant to be good for doing this. The code that I have for my project so far is:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Selected: " + e.getActionCommand());
    }
}

public class HeritageTogether {    

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("3D Heritage Model Viewer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        // File Menu, F - Mnemonic
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Areas");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        // File->New, N - Mnemonic
        JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Area1");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Area2");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Area3");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Area4");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Area5");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Area6");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        fileMenu = new JMenu("Types Of Models");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Model1");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Model2");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Model3");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Model4");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Model5");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Model6");
        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);



        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setSize(1200, 650);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Set up first subpanel
        JPanel subPanel1 = new JPanel();
        subPanel1.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(600, 650));
        subPanel1.setBackground (Color.white);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Model One");
        subPanel1.add (label1);

        // Set up second subpanel
        JPanel subPanel2 = new JPanel();
        subPanel2.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(600, 650));
        subPanel2.setBackground (Color.white);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel ("Model Two");
        subPanel2.add (label2);

        // Set up primary panel
        JPanel primary = new JPanel();
        primary.setBackground (Color.black);
        primary.add (subPanel1);
        primary.add (subPanel2);

        frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: My question is, how do I use Xmodelimporter in the code that I've provided and where

Comment: Make sure your question is in the body of the post itself, not a comment. Also, be sure you tell us what you're trying _achieve_. Merely 'using' a particular library isn't interesting: what are you trying to get it to do?